# ListView using String Array

Tags: android, string, listview

How can I give values to ListView?
When I am trying to create a ListView using String array, my process is suddently stopped.

```
     public String[] items_list=new String[100];
     items_list[0]="11";
     items_list[1]="22";
     items_list[2]="33";
     items_list[3]="44";
     ListView listitems=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items_list);
     listitems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But if i am initializing the string array with ite declaration, it is working. Why this is happend?

```
     public String[] items_list={"chocolate","lime juice","icecreame"};
```

Please help me...
Thnk you..

Comment: Hi Maya, could you copy here the error trace plz?

Comment: You have to post your logcat if you expect reasonable answers

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're making an array with 100 objects in

```
 public String[] items_list=new String[100];
 items_list[0]="11";
 ...
 items_list[3]="44";
```

But you only fill the first 4 elements, this means that the remaining 96 Strings are null. This may cause your errors when the ListView tries to fill out the list, as it assumes there are 100 elements in the list. Try only to allocate as much memory as necessary at `new String[100];`

Answer (score 0):

Tseng's answer is right on about the probable cause.  The ListView is going to see the array's size as 100 and will try and used the nulls in the remaining elements.

Use any subclass of `List<String>` (e.g., `ArrayList<String>` or `Vector<String>`) to hold your data and the adapter will function properly.